# How to remove textbox using dynamic id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have lots of dynamic textboxes with different ids. I am trying to remove them on click i have a function

```
<script>
function removing(id){
    alert(id); 
    id.remove();
    }
</script>
```

and my html textbox

```
<input type="text" id="a" name="name" onclick="removing(this.id)" />
```

when i click on it. it gives alert box but not removing textbox any help?

Comment: unfortunately it isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the element itself, so just pass `this`

```
<input type="text" id="a" name="name" onclick="removing(this)" />
```

And then the function can be

```
function removing(elm){
   alert(elm.id); 
   elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

You need to use `removeChild` from `parentNode` of element to remove it from DOM.

Comment: @AtifAzad Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the element by id using getElementById:

```
function removing(id){
    alert(id); 
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
}
```

---

But, though I would suggest you to use like @AmitJoki answered for you.